# jQuery traverse json recursive

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, recursion

I am trying to traverse a JSON object with jQuery recursive.. normally it worked , but not on the following JSON.

I want to traverse this JSON, here I uploaded an image:

[image]

For my json objects, i had this jquery function:

```
 var construct_id = "#ecommerce_form_";

 // function to traverse json objects given back from Serializer class
 function process(callback, id) {
   var key;
   for (key in callback) {

    // Handle the arrays
    if ('length' in callback[key]) {

        // Handle the end - we found a string
        if (typeof callback[key][0] == "string") {
            var field_id = construct_id + id + key;
            var err_msg = callback[key][0];

            $(field_id).tooltip('destroy');
            $(field_id).tooltip({'title': err_msg});
            $(field_id).closest('div[class="form-group"]').addClass('has-error');

            console.log(field_id, ":", err_msg);
        }
        // Else we found something else, so recurse.
        else {
            var i = 0;
            while (i < callback[key].length) {
                process(callback[key][i], key + "_" + i + "_");
                i++;
            }
        }
    }

    // Handle the objects by recursing.
    else {
        process(callback[key], key + "_");
    }
   }
 }
```

But that functions fails when trying to build the contact > addresses id with the error message:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length'
>   in This value should not be blank."

Hope you guys can help me enhancing the jQuery function, it is not 100% successfull as you can see on this json example.

Regards

Comment: Instead of posting image, post string representation of JSON

Comment: this isn't a jQuery function btw. It's just a recursive function written in plain JavaScript that uses some jQuery selectors.

Comment: Yes Mouser, nothing to do with my problem :x . I know the difference, but when i had written as title 'javascript traverse json', someone would have said 'no it is not only a javascript function, it also uses jQuery' .. Think it's of minor priority, Eyal 's answer really helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to search for the property "length" in a string, which can't be done. In the erroneous iteration: callback = obj.contacts.addresses, key = cities and then callback[key][0] = "This value should not be blank".

What you should do is check if you have reached a string **before** looking for the "length" property, and only then if you haven't found a string, begin the recursion check.
see jsfiddle example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/38d15z4o/

```
 var construct_id = "#ecommerce_form_";

// function to traverse json objects given back from Serializer class
function process(callback, id) {
   var key;
   for (key in callback) {
   // Handle the end - we found a string
   if (typeof callback[key] == "string") {
        var field_id = construct_id + id + key;
        var err_msg = callback[key][0];
        $(field_id).tooltip('destroy');
        $(field_id).tooltip({'title': err_msg});
        $(field_id).closest('div[class="form-group"]').addClass('has-error');

        console.log(field_id, ":", err_msg);
   }
    // Handle the objects and arrays by recursing.
    else {
        process(callback[key], id + key + "_");
    }
   }
 }
```

NOTE: for the error message, you are only showing the first letter of the string, I think you meant to put: err_msg = callback[key] not err_msg = callback[key][0].

Comment: "123123".hasOwnProperty('length') // returns true

Comment: @localghost Yes, but ("length" in "123123") throws an error.

Comment: Hi Eyal, that's what I also tried yesterday in the evening, but with the "=== 'string'" check, it does not build me the id anymore correctly. E.g instead of the id 'ecommerce_form_contact_addresses_0_name', it builds me the fieldid : 'ecommerce_form_addresses_0_name' , and for cities it builds me instead of id: 'ecommerce_form_contact_addresses_0_cities_0' the fieldid: 'ecommerce_form_cities_0_0 '

Comment: The problem seems building up the right id, not the "=== 'string'" check. Any idea ? Because before the error without the string check occurs, it already locks me the wrong id in the console: 
'ecommerce_form_addresses_0_name' instead of 'ecommerce_form_contact_addresses_0_name'

Comment: @nova.cp Actually there is another issue which might be causing that - the while loop inside the recursion call. You are already looping through any array you get with the "for key in callback", so there is no reason for the while loop. You should remove it and just send callback[key] to the recursion. There was also an issue with the id you passed in the recursion. See updated code.

Comment: nice, it is almost working @Eyal. At the line 'var field_id = construct_id + id + key;' i got one more problem. Each id has now at the end "underscore 0", while the '0' comes from the '+ key' variable. When i leave this variable, i have an 'underscore ' at the end of each id. Shall i just cut that 'underscore' off ? Is this than a 'clear' solution?

Comment: @nova.cp I don't see an underscore at the end, they all end with the last key (0). What do you mean "leave this variable"?

Comment: when doing the recursion: 'process(callback[key], id + key + "_");' , you pass as 'id' parameter : 'id + key + '_'. So when it comes to the === string block and enters it, the id still has the underscore at the end. I need to trim that then off, the underscore and leave the 'key' variable, because I don't want to have an 'underscore 0' at the end of each id. I've done it, and it is working. I'll accept your answer, really helped me :-)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you check for

```
typeof callback[key] === 'array'
```

Instead checking the length property?

Comment: this would end up in an endless recursion.

Comment: Why would that lead to an endless recursion while checking for length will not? Logically you want to recurse for arrays and handle everything else separately, no?